# Relation between some prime numbers and their sum

Tags: prime-numbers

Let p and q be two prime numbers less than 900 billion.
If p + 6, p + 10, q + 4, q + 10 and p + q + 1 are all primes, what is the greatest value that p + q can take?

Can you help me to solve this problem (useful relations exists but I don't know about it)?

Comment: With "first" do you mean "prime"?

Comment: yes, I mean prime numbers.

Comment: Hint: consider them mod $6$.

Comment: @Robert Israel can you help me more, I don't see how to use your hint

Comment: Try asking on [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).